# Quasi-finite and proper morphism of Noetherian schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X,Y$ be Noetherian schemes and $f: X \to Y$ be quasi-finite and proper morphism.

Is $f$ necessarily a finite morphism ?

Comment: This is correct, but not so easy to prove.

Comment: @Mohan: I see ... is there any reference, or would you mind writing a proof as an answer ?